# How to get all users that the logged in user is not friends with in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I am fully able to get all of the logged in users current friends, which I do with this query here -

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN friends
ON users.id = friends.friend_id
WHERE friends.user_id = $user_logged_in_id
```

But I want to do the opposite, and I can't figure it out.

**I am trying to do friends logic.**

I need to get all the users who the currently logged in user is not already friends with

I have a users table and a friends table to act as a many to many relationship between users and their friends. The keys in the friends table are user_id friend_id.

To illustrate that someone is friends with another user I put (say the logged in user id is 3, and friends user id is 6) `user_id = 3` and `friend_id = 6` as one row, and then put another row with the id's flipped to illustrate the friendship the other way, `user_id = 6` and `friend_id = 3`.

**users table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |     username     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     sonja12      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     dorris32     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     billy32      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |     micha97      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |     travis841    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6          |     johnny28     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**friends table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |     user_id      |     friend_id    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        3         |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        6         |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**EDIT:**

I think I have narrowed down my question a bit to be more concise.

I want to get all users from the users table where their id does not appear as a friend id beside the user_id of the current logged in user in the friends table.

Comment: Be more specific. Right now it seems like `…WHERE friends.user_id != $user_logged_in_id"` will fix it, but I'm assuming, that didn't work?

Comment: No, that returns everyone except the logged in user, and it returned the user the logged in user is already friends with twice.

I want to be able to see a list of people the logged in user is not friends with so that they can easily click an `add friend button` and add new friends. I could return all users and exclude the ones that are already friends with logged in user, but I feel like plain sql would be a much better way to go for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of the problem in a strange way. It might help to think of it as an intersection of sets you need to create as opposed to a set that exists in the absence of an id.

`SELECT id from users WHERE id != $logged_in_user AND id NOT IN ( SELECT friend_id from friends where user_id=$logged_in_user)`

Comment: Caution:  `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is terribly slow in MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames do you know of a better way than `NOT IN` to accomplish the task? I'm definitely open to it. I see some other answers here now, but not sure if any of them would be any faster. I guess I could test them all out and make note of execution time. My alternative was even slower as I was returning the whole list before and then running another separate query in a loop on each user to remove them from an array in php if they were already friends 8\

Comment: `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` -- only evaluates until it gets the answer, not building the entire list.  Or `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE .. IS NULL` -- sometimes similar code.  The composite `INDEX(user_id, friend_id)` would help significantly.

Answer (score 1):

For bigger Datasets I would use a NOT EXISTS subquery query:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id <> $user_logged_in_id
  and not exists (
    select *
    from friends f
    where f.user_id = $user_logged_in_id
      and f.friend_id = u.id
)
```

or a LEFT (ANTI) JOIN:

```
select u.*
from users u
left join friends f
  on  f.user_id = $user_logged_in_id
  and f.friend_id = u.id
where u.id <> $user_logged_in_id
  and f.friend_id is null
```

I think the execution plan for both queries should be almost the same.

Demos: http://rextester.com/KUOZ9198

Answer (score 0):

**SQL**

```
SELECT u.*
FROM usrs u
LEFT JOIN friends f
ON u.id = f.friend_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, IF(f.user_id = $user_logged_in_id, 1, 0)
HAVING MAX(IF(f.user_id = $user_logged_in_id, 1, 0)) = 0;
```

**Demo**

http://rextester.com/ELXFZ39682

**Explanation**

The query is based on your original but is grouping by each user ID so duplicates aren't returned. In order to return those that aren't friends of the logged in user, the `IF(f.user_id = $user_logged_in_id, 1, 0)` adds a generated column to the group that is set to 1 if the row is a friend of the logged in user, otherwise 0. We can then use the `HAVING MAX(...) = 0` to restrict to groups where none of the rows is a friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.username
  FROM users
       LEFT OUTER JOIN friends
    ON (friends.user_id = $user_logged_in_id and friends.friend_id = users.id)
 WHERE users.id <> $user_logged_in_id
   AND friends.friend_id is null;
```

This query is likely to be more performant than a NOT IN Sub Query if the user is expected to have lots of friends. If not NOT IN sub query performs the same if not better.

Please note the DISTINCT. You need this because the relationship is many to many.